# Присвоить значения всем ячейкам

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Есть ли в php возможность обнулить все ячейки у определённого id?
uid =222 нужно во всех ячейках записать 0

```
$mysqli->query ("UPDATE `121` SET `` = '0' WHERE `121`.`uid` =  222");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `update .. set `222` = 0, `777` = 0, ....` либо динамически вытаскивайте сведения о столбцах таблицы и стройте аналогичный запрос.

Comment: то есть получается одновременно все,не возможно?  значит нужно под каждую прописывать чтобы на 0 заменилось.Можете оформить как ответ дам лучшего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать PHP, т.е. сначала вы выбираете нужные uid

```
SELECT * FROM `name_table` WHERE uid = 222
```

Далее это всё дело в PHP преобразуете в ассоциативный массив и получаете его вида:

```
222 => [
    222 => 0,
    777 => 614,
    888 => 13,
    ...
]
```

И далее вы можете составлять запрос таким образом:

```
<?
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item){
        $sql = 'UPDATE name_table SET ';
            foreach($item as $column_name => $column_value){
                $sql .= $column_name . ' = 0,';
            }
        $sql .= ' WHERE uid = ' . $key;
    }
?>
```

И отправить на выполнение данный sql запрос.

Comment: спасибо за ответ отметил

Answer (score 2):

MySQL не поддерживает возможность обновления столбцов без явного указывания их имен. Единственный выход для вас, который я вижу — получить имена столбцов таблицы (первый запрос r БД) и обновить их способом, предусмотренным логикой приложения (второй запрос к БД).

Для того, чтобы извлечь имена столбцов таблицы `your_table`, которая принадлежит БД `your_db`, нужно выполнить такой запрос:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_db' 
        AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'
```

Вам также нужно отфильтровать эти имена, чтобы случайно не обновить данные из столбцов, которые не должны подлежать обновлению; в вашем случае это столбцы `id` (ваш `PRIMARY KEY`, если он существует) и `uid`. Это можно сделать как на уровне ЯП (PHP в вашем случае), так и на уровне БД. С PHP все понятно. Чтобы получить и отфильтровать названия столбцов на уровне БД, нужно использовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT `cols` FROM (
    SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` AS `cols`
        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_db' 
            AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'
) AS `t` WHERE `t`.`cols` NOT IN ('id', 'name')
```

Результат этого запроса — отфильтрованные названия столбцов, которые нужно обновить (обнулить в данном случае). Для этого нужно взять полученные колонки и составить из них обычный `UPDATE`-запрос. Я вижу это примерно так:

```
$cols = getCols();
$updateQuery = buildUpdateQuery($cols);

$mysqli->query($updateQuery);

function buildUpdateQuery(array $cols) {
    $setShreds = [];
    $template= 'UPDATE `your_table` AS `t` SET %s WHERE `t`.`uid` = 222';

    foreach ($cols as $col)
        $setShreds[] = $col . '=0';

    return sprintf(
        $template,
        implode(',', $sqlSetShreds)
    );
}

function getCols() {
    $sql = (
        SELECT `cols` FROM (
            SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` AS `cols`
                FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
                WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_db' 
                    AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table'
        ) AS `t` WHERE `t`.`cols` NOT IN ('id', 'uid')
    );

    $res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    return $res['cols'];
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что приведенный в качестве примеров код — всего лишь каркас, поэтому настоятельно не рекомендуется его использовать в подобном виде в вашем проекте. Не забудьте обернуть все это дело некой абстракцией, которая обеспечит удобное повторное использование кода.

Comment: спасибо за ответ поставил вам галочку